# How to write a change function for kendo scheduler Resource template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I Have the following resources in my kendo scheduler. can anyone suggest to me how to sort the second dropdownlist based on selected criteria of the first dropdown list? 
below is my code

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<Proj.Models.Data.Scheduler>()
.Name("scheduler")
.Date(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day))
.StartTime(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1, 7, 00, 00))
.Editable()
.Views(views =>
{
    views.DayView();
    views.WeekView();
    views.MonthView(MonthView => MonthView.Selected(true));
})
.Resources(resource =>
{     
    resource.Add(m => m.TypeID) //need to get the selected id of this dropdownlist and load the second dropdown
        .Title("Type")
        .Name("maintype")
        .DataTextField("TYPENAME")
        .DataValueField("TYPECODE")
        .BindTo(@proj.Models.GeneralModule.lstlookup);

    resource.Add(m => m.SubTypeID)
        .Title("Sub Type")
        .DataTextField("MASTERNAME")
        .DataValueField("MASTERID")
        .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("loadSubTypeScheduler", "Config").Data("DataFilter")).ServerFiltering(false));

})
.DataSource(d => d
    .Model(m =>
    {
        m.Id(f => f.TaskID);
        m.Field(f => f.OwnerID);
    })
.ServerOperation(true)
)
)
```

Can anyone help me with this? I was trying with some class selector using jQuery, but it is not happening. My requirement is to filter the subtype dropdown based on the Type dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Use the change event of the first dropdown

```
.Events(e =>
            {
                e.Change("onChange")
            })
```

then create your jQuery function:

```
function onChange(e){
                    var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item);
    var itemText = dataItem.Text;
    var itemValue = dataItem.Value;        
    }
```

Comment: Sorry it cannot be used in resources.`.Events()` is not included in resouces. We can give `.Events()` not for a particular resource